# Asymptotic stability of linear time varying system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes, linear-control

Consider a linear time varying homogeneous system:
$$\dot{x}=A(t)x$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A(t)$ is a $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix satisfying $A(t)\to -I_n$ as $t\to\infty$. Suppose $A$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$. Notice that $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Is it true that $x(t)$ is asymptotically stable? Is it true that $x(t)$ is Lyapunov stable?

---

For Lyapunov stability, I find a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279224/stability-of-linear-time-varying-systems). Since $A(t)\to -I_n$, when $t>0$ is large enough, $A(t)$ will be eventually negative definite, so by using the result in the link, it seems we have Lyapunov stability.

---

For asymptotic stability, it seems to be possible because here we don't have the situation that $A(t)$ will vanish very fast, as shown in several counterexamples in the above link. It is obvious that if $A(t)$ is exactly $-I_n$, it will be asymptotically stable. Also, the fact that $A(t)$ is symmetric may be essential.

Comment: Is $A$ continuous, bounded, whatever?

Comment: It is a continuously differentiable function in time $t$ on $[0,\infty)$. I have added the assumption.

Comment: You can use the function $V(x) = {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$ to show that there is some time $T$ such that $\dot{V}$ is bounded on $[0,T]$ and $ \le -{1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$ for $t>T$. Apply this to a basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "a basis"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n(t) = \lambda_1(A(t))$, the $\max$ eigenvalue of $A(t)$. $n$ is continuous and $n(t) \to -1$. Choose $T>0$ such that
$n(t) \le -{1 \over 2}$ for $t > T$ and let $B=\sup_{t \in [0,T]} n(t)$.

Pick some $x$ and let $V_x(t) = {1 \over 2} \|x(t)\|^2$, where $x$ is the response of the system to the initial condition $x$. We see that
$\dot{V_x}(t) = x(t)^T A(t) x(t) \le 2n(t) V_x(t)$.

On $[0,T]$, $\dot{V_x}(t) \le 2B V_x(t)$ and so $V_x(t) \le V_x(0) e^{2Bt} \le V_x(0) e^{2BT}$ and similarly, for $t >T$,
$V_x(t) \le V_x(T) e^{-(t-T)} \le V_x(0) e^{2BT} e^{-(t-T)}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta = e^{-BT}$, then if $\|x_0\| < \delta$ we see that $\|x(t)\| < \epsilon$ for $t \ge 0$. Furthermore,
$x(t) \to 0$, hence the system is asymptotically stable (in fact exponentially stable).

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: You are very welcome; in general, it might be better to wait a few days before upvoting in case a better answer arrives. Also, it gives time to uncover any bugs in the above.

Comment: Got it. I realized that this is not a tough question, so I upvoted and accepted it.